# Mutex implementation in x86 memory model

Tags: x86, mutex, shared-memory

In a recent interview I waqs asked how a mutex is implemented in an x86 architecture. He mentioned that there are two steps when lock is called on a mutex. I was not able to answer so he further explained by saying how a multi-core or multi-cpu architecture with shared memory would implement a mutex.

I'd appreciate if somebody can shed some light on to this or give me a reference to follow.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the `futex(7)` man page on Linux could be relevant.

Comment: google [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868007/on-multicore-x86-systems-are-mutexes-implemented-using-a-lockd-instruction) or even [that](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?t=14261).